# Find the google loginform with java pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search the google loginform within the html code with a simple java pattern. The loginform looks like this:

```
<form ... id="gaia_loginform" ... > ... </form>
```

I am using the following pattern to find it:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<form[^>]*id=[\"|']gaia_loginform[\"|'][^>]*>(.*)</form>")
Matcher mat = pat.find(html); // html is the complete website

System.out.println(mat.group(1)); // throws exception
```

Actually it should the contents between the two tags. Thanks for advice what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: You don't need `|` inside `[..]` (it represents `|` literal there, not `OR` operator). Also `(.*)` should probably be reluctant `(.*?)`. But best advice I can give you is to abandon idea of using regex with HTML. Use parser instead (http://jsoup.org/ has quite nice CSS selectors where you could simply select `form#gaia_loginform`).

Comment: @Pshemo the thing is i do not want to use any third party libs for this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `Matcher`. Here is how it should be used (an example of using the Matcher):

```
String str = "<form ... id=\"gaia_loginform\" ... >\nCONTENT\n</form>";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<form\\b[^>]*\\bid=[\"']gaia_loginform[\"'][^>]*>(.*?)</form>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/tjcbeJ)

**For parsing HTML you should consider using HTML parsers, even if you are not using them now.**

A couple of words on the regex: I am using `Pattern.DOTALL` flag when declaring the regex as `.` should be able to match newline symbols. Tag and id names must be matches as whole words and thus I am using `\\b`. Instead of `.*` we are safer with `.*?` (lazy matching), it will capture as few characters as possible.

Comment: Thanks that really helps me. The pat.find was just a misspelling of mine.